# PDO fetchAll PDO::FETCH_COLUMN equivalent to PDO::FETCH_NUM?

Tags: php, sql, pdo

Is this code

```
/* already set up a query with one column in result */

$row['fk_user_pks'] = $q->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_COLUMN);
```

equivalent to:

```
/* already set up a query with one column in result row */

$result = $q->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_NUM);
$row['fk_user_pks'] = array();
foreach ($result as $r) {
     $row['fk_user_pks'][] = $r[0];
}
```

Comment: What makes you unable to run and see?

Comment: @YourCommonSense, laziness. Btw I like your safemysql. :) Please add more docs to it.

Comment: I don't understand it. I always have a test file ready, to verify whatever idea struck me - in a second. And I take this file as most reliable source of information I can have, even better than PHP docs. Not to mention Stack Overflow, which rated way down below. What topic you want to be explained in the docs?

Comment: @YourCommonSense it's psychology. Maybe I will open that test file. :) Anyway, I would like to see some docs on INSERT, UPDATE etc. A complete CRUD example.

Comment: @YourCommonSense, ok it didn't take a me a second, more like 20 minutes.  :)

Comment: Ah, sure. If you didn't have a database already - yes. surely I have it as well. A table called 'users' in the test database. So, it have to take me indeed seconds to copy-paste the code and add print_r's

Comment: Actually, I have a CRUD example, almost finished. Still almost... Hope I'll overcome *my* laziness and let it out :)

Answer (score 3):

Yes, they are equivalent as is shown here:

```
<?php


$dbh = new PDO('sqlite::memory:');
$dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);


$dbh->exec(
    "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `test1` ( " .
    " `id` INTEGER, " .
    " `whatever` char(10)," .
    " PRIMARY KEY (`id`) " .
    ")"
);

for ($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++) {
    $dbh->exec("INSERT INTO test1 (whatever) VALUES ('hejsan')");
}


$q = $dbh->prepare('SELECT id FROM test1');
$q->execute(array());
$ids = $q->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_COLUMN, 0);

print_r($ids);

$q->execute(array());
$result = $q->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_NUM);
$ids = array();
foreach ($result as $r) {
     $ids[] = $r[0];
}

print_r($ids);
```